# R: Error Message of cast "unimplemented type 'list' in 'listgreater"

Tags: r, casting

Using the following commands (x is a table with 3 columns A, B and C)

```
library(reshape)
cast(x, A~B)
```

Following error appears:

```
Using C as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
Error in order(A = list("xxx",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'listgreater'
```

What does it means and how to solve it?

---

I guess it maybe due to the dataframe's data format (correct me if I am wrong).  As i did a test of the format of the table x and y with str command.

```
str(x) returns
$ A: List of 6
..$ : chr "xxx"
....
$ B:chr "yyy" "yy2" ....
...
$ C: List of 6
..$ : num 22.....
...
```

For another table y with column D E and F,  no error message appears when I run the cast command.

```
str(y) shows that all D E F columns are Factor w/ 6 levels....
```

How can I make cast work for list and num containing dataframe x?

Comment: Thank HTH, I tried one, but the result of str(x) is the same after doing "x <- as.data.frame(x)".  The same error message appears too.  maybe I did not identify the problem of the dataframe correctly yet?  Is Cast can only be used for factor, not number nor chr?

Comment: lol, HTH means hope that helps. Comment my anwser next time ;-) , so I know someone commented on it.  Could you post some more info on x? A reproducible example would be great. Try using dput(x).

Answer (score 8):

use

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, unlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first data.frame is not a data.frame but a list. Transforming to a data.frame will solve the problem. Use:

```
x <- as.data.frame(x)
library(reshape)
cast(x, A~B)
```

HTH